# Oracle 12c - how to remove the SID from an already dropped DB

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, oracle12c

Been using T-sql for years but new to Oracle . . .

There's a DB instance that was installed under the wrong user, so I dropped the DB, and cleaned up files. Now, I'm trying to setup the database under the correct login, but the old SID still exists.

How do I get rid of the SID of an already dropped DB? I've removed the SID entry from the registry, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

EDIT: Found the missing piece. Had to get rid of \app\admin[DBNAME]. That did the trick.

Comment: So you want to clean up the registry? When you say 'remove the SID' - remove from where, exactly?

Comment: This situation is that I need to install the exact same database name & SID under a different windows user. When I try this, Oracle tells me that the SID conflicts with an existing one. I went through the registry and found the SID entry and deleted it but Oracle says it's still there.

Comment: Your basic terminology is confusing.  You talk "installing" a database under a certain user.  That sounds like installing the _software_.   Once the software is installled, you can then _create_ a database.  The software installation allows the _option_ of _also_ createing a database.  But installing software and creating databases are two distinctly different operations.  Please clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Not the software, the user under which the specific database is setup via Database Configuration Assistant. Where I'm presently working, they setup "Instances" by username. Can't explain why, as I just started here and it's my first time touching Oracle. I only know that for the application to work correctly, the database (not the software) has to be setup under the instance's username.

Comment: As far as Oracle is concerned, there is no connection between a database and the OS user that ran DBCA to create the database.  So I haven't a clue as to what bizarre  setup standards your shop may be using.  Be aware that the term 'database' doesn't mean the same thing in Oracle as it does in MSSQL.   An MSSQL 'database' is more akin to an Oracle 'schema'.

Comment: I see in your edit that you were able to fix the problem.  I'd be curious to know exactly what you did to drop the original DB.

Comment: @EdStevens - I originally dropped the DB via SQPLUS command prompt. I've since learned that the cleaner way is via the DB Config Assistant. (Correct me if I'm wrong)